# Redirect HTTP to HTTPS Htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, http, redirect, https

I need a script to .htaccess to 301 redirect http to https, but a page needs to be accessed by HTTP. Example:

`example.com/*` redirects to `https://example.com/*`
`example.com/page1` not redirect to `https://example.com/page1`

Comment: What are your current rules that you have to redirect to https?

Comment: All site http:// example.com need to redirect https:// example.com. But the page http:// example.com/page1 must be accessible via http

Comment: I got what you were asking, what I wanted to see is what rules you already had so they could be modified.

Comment: I have only: RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

Answer (score 0):

Just use this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^.*$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
```

So it will just set your SSL to https for all pages, even if someone access it via http.

Use this if you want to force https for all except the directory /page1

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !page1 [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Ok,
But I need the page "example.com/page1" also is accessible via http

Comment: Now to access the directory "page1" via http is redirecting to home